# Perl LWP::UserAgent hangs for 120 seconds seemingly randomly against a given server

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, lwp, lwp-useragent

I noticed a delay of approximately 120 seconds between handling the `response_data` and `response_done` events in [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize) with a given https web site. I checked with a normal web browser and do not experience this slowness so I suspect there is something I must do wrong.

Here is what I did to trace the events (for some reason [`use LWP::Debug qw(+)`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::Debug) did not do anything):

```perl
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);
use IO::Handle;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(
  timeout     => 3,
  autocheck   => 1,       # check success of each query
  stack_depth => 0,       # no keeping history
  keep_alive  => 50,      # connection pool
);

$mech->agent_alias( 'Windows IE 6' );
open my $debugfile, '>traffic.txt';
$debugfile->autoflush(1);

$mech->add_handler( request_send => sub {
    my $cur_time = gettimeofday();
    my $req = shift;
    print $debugfile "\n$cur_time === BEGIN HTTP REQUEST ===\n";
    print $debugfile $req->dump();
    print $debugfile "\n$cur_time ===   END HTTP REQUEST ===\n";
    return
  }
);
$mech->add_handler( response_header => sub {
    my $cur_time = gettimeofday();
    my $res = shift;
    print $debugfile "\n$cur_time === GOT RESPONSE HDRS ===\n";
    print $debugfile $res->dump();
    return
  }
);
$mech->add_handler( response_data => sub {
    my $cur_time = gettimeofday();
    my $res = shift;
    my $content_length = length($res->content);
    print $debugfile "$cur_time === Got response data chunk resp size = $content_length ===\n";
    return
  }
);
$mech->add_handler( response_done => sub {
    my $cur_time = gettimeofday();
    my $res = shift;
    print $debugfile "\n$cur_time === BEGIN HTTP RESPONSE ===\n";
    print $debugfile $res->dump();
    print $debugfile "\n===   END HTTP RESPONSE ===\n";
    return
  }
);
```

And here is a excerpt of the traces (URLs and cookies are obfuscated):

```
1347463214.24724 === BEGIN HTTP REQUEST ===
GET https://...
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Referer: https://...
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Cookie: ...
Cookie2: $Version="1"

(no content)

1347463214.24724 ===   END HTTP REQUEST ===

1347463216.13134 === GOT RESPONSE HDRS ===
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 12 Sep 2012 15:20:08 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
...
Server: Lotus-Domino
Content-Length: 377806
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Last-Modified: Fri, 07 Sep 2012 06:25:33 GMT
Client-Peer: ...
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: ...
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: ...
Client-SSL-Cipher: DES-CBC3-SHA
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL

(no content)
1347463216.48305 === Got response data chunk resp size = 4096 ===

1347463337.98131 === BEGIN HTTP RESPONSE ===
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 12 Sep 2012 15:20:08 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
...
Server: Lotus-Domino
Content-Length: 377806
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Last-Modified: Fri, 07 Sep 2012 06:25:33 GMT
Client-Date: Wed, 12 Sep 2012 15:22:17 GMT
Client-Peer: ...
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: ...
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: ...
Client-SSL-Cipher: DES-CBC3-SHA
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL

PK\3\4\24\0\6\0\10\0\0\0!\0\x88\xBC\21Xi\2\0\0\x84\22\0\0\23\0\10\2[Content_Types].xml \xA2...
(+ 377294 more bytes not shown)

===   END HTTP RESPONSE ===
```

During the “Got response data chunk” and “BEGIN HTTP RESPONSE” messages, you can see a 121.5 seconds gap. I have the feeling that sometimes `LWP::UserAgent` hangs for two minutes after having received the full amount of data.

Do you have any clue where that could come from?

**EDIT** here is a screenshot in Wireshark : I get the FIN/ACK message after 120 seconds…

[image: Wireshark Excerpt]

Thanks

Comment: The documentation for `LWP::Debug` says this: *LWP::Debug used to provide tracing facilities, but these are not used by LWP any more*

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks, that answers another problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Borodin's answer I found a way to fix it:

I modified the `response_data` event handler sub this way:

```
if($res->header('Content-Length') == length($res->content)) {
    die "OK"; # Got whole data, not waiting for server to end the communication channel.
}
return 1; # In other cases make sure the handler is called for subsequent chunks
```

And then if `X-Died` header is equal to `OK` then ignore errors in the caller.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is likely that your transaction is actually taking that long. The documentation for [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) says this

> [The response_data handler] needs to return a TRUE value to be called
>   again for subsequent chunks for the same request

so, because your handler returns nothing, you are tracing only the first returned data packet

According to your output the first 4KB of data arrives in 2.2 seconds, or roughly 2KB per second. The entire data is 369KB long so you would expect to receive 92 more data packets, and at 2KB per second it would take three minutes to transmit. You get your response in two minutes so I think your times are reasonable

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I indeed forgot to return 1 in that handler, but it actually is not what I needed (2.2 seconds includes the processing time on the server which is long. Actually the following chunks come very fast. See Wireshark screenshot.) Though +1 for the help and the remark on that handler.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I found a way to circumvent the problem. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old now, but I had what appears to be the same problem recently. It only occurred when the size of the unencrypted HTTPS response, including headers, was exactly 1024 bytes. Benoit seems to have had responses of exactly 4096 bytes, so perhaps multiples of 1024 are significant. I didn't have control of the server, so I couldn't produce test responses of arbitrary length, nor could I reproduce the problem on any other server. The occurrence at 1024 bytes was repeatable though.

Looking around the LWP code (v6.05), I found that sysread is asked to read 1024 bytes at a time. So, the first time it returns all 1024 bytes. It is then immediately called for a second time, and rather than returning 0, indicating that there is no more data, it returns undef, indicating an error, and sets errno to EAGAIN, indicating that there is more data, but it's not available yet. This leads to a select on the socket, which hangs because there isn't going to be more data. It takes 120 seconds to time out, after which what data we do have is returned, which happens to be the correct result. Therefore, we get no errors, just a long delay.

I didn't have convenient enough access to use Benoit's solution. Instead, my workaround was to extend the HTTPS handling code to check for the above situation and return 0 instead of undef:

```
package LWP::Protocol::https::Socket;

sub sysread {
    my $self = shift;
    my $result = $self->SUPER::sysread(@_);
    # If we get undef back then some error occurred. If it's EAGAIN
    # then that ought to mean that there is more data to read but
    # it's not available yet. We suspect the error may be false.
    # $_[2] is the offset, so if it's defined and non-zero we have
    # some data in the buffer.
    # $_[0] is the buffer, so check it for an entire HTTP response,
    # including the headers and the body. If the length specified
    # by Content-Length is exactly the length of the body we have in
    # the buffer, then take that as being complete and return a length
    # here instead. Since it's unlikely that anything was read, the
    # buffer will not have increased in size and the result will be zero
    # (which was the expected result anyway).
    if (!defined($result) &&
        $!{EAGAIN} &&
        $_[2] &&
        $_[0] =~ /^HTTP\/\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\s+.*\s+content-length\s*:\s*(\d+).*?\r?\n\r?\n(.*)$/si &&
        length($2) == $1) {
            return length($_[0]) - $_[2]; # bufferlen - offset
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alan, 
I have recieved the same behavior on my system. 
For content length 1024, 2048, 3072 bytes and so on

The solution of this problem is to upgrade Net::HTTP to 6.09 version and above